# SSIS Ftp Connection resets to value after debug

Tags: sql-server, ftp, ssis

My SSIS package is driving me crazy.

I have an ftp connection using my local filezilla ftp server. I connect to it using IP and TestConnection in FTP Connection Editor Manager says connection is ok. Everything looks fine until I press run or debug where I see the old ftp details when I click edit on ftp connection. Hence the task fails. When I stop debug I see that ftp connection has been set to the old one. I searched the entire project for the old ftp name and replaced everything with the new one. But this still happens:)

Am I not allowed to write IP in the **Server Name** part. Using everywhere else, I can connect to the ftp as follows. `ftp://127.0.0.5/folder/`

**Edit:**I just found that when I stop debugging and the properties window was open during debug, I can see the connection string with correct servername but the servername part is wrong. And it probably fails to connect somehow because it is using the old servername info.

Comment: Do you have a forgotten expression which sets it somewhere? This would change the value at run-time.

Comment: Do you have configuration/expressions applied to it?

Comment: If you don't already have it, download and install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) as it will help illuminate items with expressions and configurations

Comment: I dont have any specific expression to change it. I'll check the configurations again.

Comment: @billinkc yup, I had configs. If you write it as answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you do not have an Expression or Configuration applied to your Connection Manager. There are two distinct aspects to SSIS development: the design-time environment and the run-time environment. What looks valid in BIDS/SSDT may be radically different that the values used during execution based on configuration (files, SQL Server table, environment, etc) or expressions (or expressions based on configuration).

The other thing to be aware of is that the value of a Variable in SSIS's Variable window remains constant with the design-time value. Many people set breakpoints, see the value in the Variable's window is "wrong" and assume it's not working right. Instead, one needs to look at the Locals window and expand the Variables collection. There you'll be able to find the current value of a Variable.

If you do not already have it installed, [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) is a wonderful tool for quickly illuminating what objects in an SSIS package have configuration and/or expressions applied to them. The SSIS team has baked some of this functionality into the 2012 release of SSIS but it's still a very useful and free add-on for anyone doing MS BI development.